# Temp directory for unrar

Tags: unrar

and thanks in advance for all answer.
I'm running slitaz on a very small and just tailored patition, using unrar as root to decompress a file on a mounted external HD maybe I didn't specify the destination path so I failed to unrar the file but also the partition containing the filesystem get 100% full now and I wasn't able to find were unrar put its temp files so I can't delete them manually to make my Linux works correctly again.
Tanks to all.

Comment: If you don't specifi a destination path, unar will use the current dir. Use history command to know where you run the command.

Comment: Ok founded a file on / filesistem directory